# How do I store texts with line breaks in database?

Tags: html, database, mongodb, web, nosql

I'm a newbie web developer.

I am trying to make my own web based text editor application thus I need this info.

How do I store text with line breaks in database.
I am thinking to use MongoDB.

Also, I'm interested in knowing:

1. What database YouTube uses to store comments?
2. What database stackoverflow uses to store comments?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

When deciding what type of database to use for your own project, it is more important to keep in mind what features of that database that you may need for your own project.

YouTube and Stackoverflow both use SQL databases, but the result that you are trying to accomplish can be performed in a NoSQL database like MongoDB as well.

If you have a fixed schema and need to perform table joins in order to compile all of your data, a SQL database might be the way to go.

If your schema is more flexible and your data would benefit from document-based storage and loading, then a NoSQL database is the way to go.